# How to make v-btn to not initiate route on click but still show active state based on route?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have nice menu in toolbar and I use v-btn as activator so some items are without menu some with. Problem is on mobile devices wher hover dont work.
when I click on button it always trigger the route. I set :on route so it is highlighted automatically based on current route. So dont know how to make v-btn to not triger route but just open a menu but still show selection based on route, well... sub-route of his child

```
<v-menu class="toolbarMenu" offset-y open-on-hover transition="slide-y-transition">
          <v-btn :to="{ path: `${constants.portfolioPath}`}" flat slot="activator">
            <v-icon class="hidden-sm-and-down" left>work_outline</v-icon>
            {{titles.portfolioMenu}}
          </v-btn>
          <v-list two-line>
            <ListItem :subtitle="titles.portfolioProjectsPage"
                      :title="titles.portfolioProjectsMenu"
                      :to="{name:constants.portfolioProjectsRoute}" icon="business"/>
            <ListItem :subtitle="titles.portfolioVideosPage"
                      :title="titles.portfolioVideosMenu"
                      :to="{name:constants.portfolioVideosRoute}" icon="movie"/>
            <ListItem :subtitle="titles.portfolioPicturesPage"
                      :title="titles.portfolioPicturesMenu"
                      :to="{name:constants.portfolioPicturesRoute}" icon="image"/>
          </v-list>
        </v-menu>
```

Comment: Is that v-btn component from Vuetify?

Answer (score 1):

Seems Vuetify buttons use vue-router's router-link to handle clicks and router redirects, therefore you should be able to override default behaviour of that button.

```
<v-btn :to="{ path: `${constants.portfolioPath}`}" 
       flat 
       slot="activator"
       @click.native.prevent="someEmptyMethod"

>
    <v-icon class="hidden-sm-and-down" left>work_outline</v-icon>
    {{titles.portfolioMenu}}
</v-btn>
```

Then in the script part.

```js
methods: {
    someEmptyMethod() {
        // there could be also set some action
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you WERY ! much my friend  I wasted so much time yesterday on this but your answer guided me to perfect solution even though it was not exact

Answer (score 1):

So in the end it was a little more complicated... but solvable. Just relevant code:

```
<template>
   ...
    <v-menu class="toolbarMenu" offset-y open-on-hover 
            transition="slide-y-transition" v-model="isPortfolioMenuShown">
      <v-btn :class="{'disable-events': isPortfolioMenuShown}" :to="{ path: `${constants.portfolioPath}`}"
             @click.native.stop.prevent.capture="onPortfolioMainMenuButtonClick()"
             flat slot="activator">
        <v-icon class="hidden-sm-and-down" left>work_outline</v-icon>
        {{titles.portfolioMenu}}
      </v-btn>
      <v-list two-line>
        <ListItem :subtitle="titles.portfolioProjectsPage"
                  :title="titles.portfolioProjectsMenu"
                  :to="{name:constants.portfolioProjectsRoute}" icon="business"/>
        <ListItem :subtitle="titles.portfolioVideosPage"
                  :title="titles.portfolioVideosMenu"
                  :to="{name:constants.portfolioVideosRoute}" icon="movie"/>
        <ListItem :subtitle="titles.portfolioPicturesPage"
                  :title="titles.portfolioPicturesMenu"
                  :to="{name:constants.portfolioPicturesRoute}" icon="image"/>
      </v-list>
    </v-menu>
...
</template>

    <style lang="stylus" scoped>
       .toolbarMenu
         top: 50px

      .disable-events {
        pointer-events: none
      }
    </style>

    export default class... {    
        isPortfolioMenuShown = false

        onPortfolioMainMenuButtonClick = () => this.isPortfolioMenuShown = true
    }
```